# SQL - How to get MAX of SUM?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, max

I need help. I have table Employees and table Departments. And I need to get the department, which has the biggest sum of salaries.
I try this:

```
SELECT department_name,MAX(sum_salary) as sum_salary 
FROM (SELECT department_name,SUM(salary) AS sum_salary 
FROM EMPLOYEES,DEPARTMENTS 
WHERE DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID 
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_NAME)
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_NAME;
```

But the result is the list of departments, not only one value.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: WHich dbms? sql-server, mysql or? btw, your query doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's a sql from oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, in the case of ties, you only want one, then `order by` and some form of getting one row works.  The ANSI standard method is:

```
SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, SUM(e.salary) AS sum_salary 
FROM EMPLOYEES e JOIN
     DEPARTMENTS d
     ON d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID 
GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
ORDER BY SUM(e.salary) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Note the use of proper `JOIN` syntax and table aliases.

EDIT:

Oracle 12g supports the above syntax.  You can do it in earlier versions as:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, SUM(e.salary) AS sum_salary 
      FROM EMPLOYEES e JOIN
           DEPARTMENTS d
           ON d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID 
      GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
      ORDER BY SUM(e.salary) DESC
     ) t
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

[Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/faede/6) a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Won't this return the _minimal_ sum of salaries? I'm assuming unqualified `order by` is ascending as in T-SQL.

Comment: I made it exactly like you and the answer is: SQL command not properly ended :-/

Comment: @BobJarvis . . . The sum should be `desc`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  min(max(department_name)) keep (dense_rank last order by sum(salary))
    as department_name,
  min(sum(salary)) keep (dense_rank last order by sum(salary)) 
    as sum_salary
from EMPLOYEES join DEPARTMENTS using(department_id)
group by department_id
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d1d42/1)

Answer (score 0):

Wait - there is Yet Another Way:

```
WITH SUM_SAL AS (SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, SUM(e.SALARY) AS SUM_SALARY
                   FROM EMPLOYEES e
                   INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS d
                     ON d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
                   GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_NAME),
     MAX_SAL AS (SELECT MAX(SUM_SALARY) AS MAX_SALARY
                   FROM SUM_SAL)
SELECT s.DEPARTMENT_NAME, m.MAX_SALARY
  FROM SUM_SAL s
  INNER JOIN MAX_SAL m
    ON m.MAX_SALARY = s.SUM_SALARY;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/faede/2)

Best of luck.